# ionic3 update checkbox event value

Tags: ionic3

i am trying to figure out if a checkbox is checked or not when user clicks on it.

below is the code

```
 <ion-item-group>
                  <ion-item-divider color="light"><ion-icon name="warning" style="color:#FFBA55"></ion-icon>&nbsp;Overdue Tasks</ion-item-divider>
                  <ion-item> <ion-label class="label-style">item 1</ion-label>
                              <ion-checkbox (ionChange)="updateToDo($event)"></ion-checkbox></ion-item>
                  <ion-item> <ion-label class="label-style">item 2</ion-label>
                              <ion-checkbox (ionChange)="updateToDo($event)"></ion-checkbox></ion-item>

                </ion-item-group>
```

the updateTodo looks like:

```
updateToDo(event){

    alert(event.target.checked)
  }
```

but this throws undefined action for target property on event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `checked` is a property of the event passed to the function.

You can simply use `event.checked` instead of `event.target.checked`.